# Tomcat 6 doesn't start my app on Ubuntu Karmic, which works flawlessly on Lucid

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu-9.04

I am having some issues with Tomcat 6 on Ubuntu Karmic. It doesn't start the app failing with various errors.

The first on is:

```
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.util.PropertyPermission spring.security.strategy read)
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:342)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:553)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(SecurityManager.java:1302)
at java.lang.System.getProperty(System.java:669)
at org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder.<clinit>(SecurityContextHolder.java:53)
... 54 more
```

This is weird, because the very same app runs on Tomcat 6 on Lucid very well. The policy configuration file is the same, I checked. When I add the permission to the `conf/policy.d/04webapps.policy` file:

```
permission java.util.PropertyPermission "spring.security.strategy", "read";
```

it then fails with NoClassDefFoundError:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer
```

Though cglib is in the lib directory of the war

Please help, I can't find any clue on the reason of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got it now. By default, in Lucid tomcat runs without a security manager. By default in Karmic security manager is enabled. If it is enabled, you need to fine-tune it for your application needs.